# Appletalk access to root

Tags: macos, netatalk

> For some bizarre reason people are "answering" this Question more than a year after it was asked - after no Answers at the time, despite significant OS changes, changes to `netatalk` and Apple abandoning `afp`. I would delete it, but this isn't possible because of the "Answers".

I am using `netatalk` on my Pi (running Raspbian) to allow access from my Mac.
This has been working well for my Home directory, but I have tried to get access to the Pi root without success.

I can connect OK, and see all the root directories, but not their contents.
If I change the path from `/` to `/etc` I can see the contents, and subdirectories.

The relevant content of `AppleVolumes.default`

```
:DEFAULT: options:upriv,usedots

# By default all users have access to their home directories.
~/                      $hHome

:PIROOT: options:upriv,usedots,ro
/etc                    "$hRoot"
```

Any advice to access root would be appreciated. I am not sure if this is the best site for the question. I will try others if no one hare can help.

Comment: @Winterflags It would have been smarter to ask about this on [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) rather than placing a bounty here -- unless Milliways has already solved this and posts and answer, of course.

Comment: @goldilocks Oh okay. I hope someone sees the question.

Comment: I'd recommend using sshfs to mount your pi's drive on your mac with macfusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but I think your connecting User has no rights to write to `/`.

Netatalk needs the connecting user to be able to r/w to `/.AppleDouble` which is a folder where files metadata/resource forks are
kept.

- Or it's a bug being talked about [here](http://blog.ibd.com/howto/bonjour-avahi-netatalk-to-share-files-files-between-ubuntu-10-4-mac-os-x/comment-page-1/#comment-1191)
- A workaround would be to just list all directories of `/` in your AppleVolumes.default

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I give the connecting (OS X) user r/w permissions to `~/.AppleDouble`?

Comment: Wasn't the issue more that the user wants to login as 'root' so everything is open across Netatalk to the storage of the PI. This enables them to make modifications using the Mac finder and some powerful editors like TextWrangler instead of dealing with the PI's command line editors.  Looking for same myself....

Comment: the 'root' account should not be used by a human. on iOS, one should always use the 'mobile' user.

Answer (score 1):

You can't login as root user to see the entire contents of the pi's storage. There is code in Netatalk that prevents the root user from logging in.

If you do share the root of the storage system via Netatalk, and if your folder is at the root of the disk and if that folder permits the logged in Appletalk user to list it's content, Netatalk filters that folder out of the listing under the root of the storage aka "/". Aggravating.

For example, if you tell Netatalk to share the root of the storage by adding:

```
/               "π Tin"
```

to the  `/etc/netatalk/Applevolumes.default` file on your pi before the `# End of File` you will likely see a nearly empty volume = your when you open the `π Tin` volume from your Mac (aka file share, shared folder):

[image]

Then for fun, set the "execute" bit off on the `/man` directory on your pi like this:

```
sudo chmod o-x /man
```

That directory or "folder" should have shown under the `π Tin` volume with a whole bunch of others when you first opened it...but it didn't. Now, after executing the command line above and then opening the `π Tin` volume, you will magically see the "man" folder show up:

[image]
(you may have to "disconnect" and "reconnect" from your Mac to see the changes faster)

But because you told the pi's file system to *not* allow "others" to "execute" aka display folder contents listing, you can't open it from your Mac regardless of the "read" setting on the folder.

[image]

and of course changing it back to allow "execute" hence get a folder contents listing:

```
sudo chmod o+x /man
```

results in the folder disappearing from the`π Tin` volume aka root of the pi's boot volume you are looking at on your Mac desktop:

[image]

(note, you can add a file to the pi's storage root and it shows up fine so you know it is working... feature-error.jpg for example)

Cannot login as root to see the whole pi. Cannot see the root of the disk. Both intentional. Here is the code in Netatalk that keeps the 'root' user from logging in for example: [auth.c file under GitHub see line 224](https://github.com/adiknoth/netatalk-debian/blob/master/etc/afpd/auth.c)

How many wasted hours have how many people put in discovering this artificial set of limitations?

Answer (score 0):

To access `root` of your Pi from any guest authentication, try this on `afp.conf`:

```
[Global]
  uam list = uams_guest.so
  force user = root
  rwlist = nobody
```

See documentation: http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.1/htmldocs/afp.conf.5.html